# How to index words with special character in Solr

Tags: solr

I would like to index some words with special characters all together.

For example, given `m&m`, I would like to index it as a whole, rather than delimiting it as `m` and `m` (normally `&` would be considered as a delimiter).

Is there a way to achieve this by using standard tokenizer/filter or should I have to write one myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically text field type filter out special characters before indexing. and you can use string type but it is not advisable for searching on it. you can use **types option** of **WordDelimiterFilterFactory**  and you can convert those special characters to alphabetical

% => percent
& => and

Comment: `% => percent` is an invalid rule. Examples here are correct:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2059

Answer (score 3):

A Standard Tokenizer factory splits/tokenizes the given text at special characters. To index with special characters you could either write your own custom tokenizer or you can do the following:

- Take a list of characters, at which you want to tokenize/split the
  text. For eg, my list is `{" ",";"}`.
- Use a [PatternTokenizer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternTokenizerFactory) with the
  above list of characters, instead of the StandardTokenizer. Your
  configuration will look like:

  ```
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=" |;" />
    </analyzer>
  ```

Comment: Hi @Mavellin, we had same requirement, and applied `Solr.PatternTokinerFactory` as a solution, but it causes some weird issue. Please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105450/solr-fuzzy-search-issue-with-patterntokenizer-factory

Answer (score 1):

you can use WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory.

http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-WhiteSpaceTokenizer

It will tokenize only on whitespaces. For example,

"m&m" will be considered as a single token and so it would indexed like that