# Lucene: Search for numbers with characters like % attached to them

Tags: lucene

I am using Lucene to Index documents and Search for values like $5000 and 90%, but in my search results, I find that the standardanalyzer deletes the $ and % while indexing the code. So I just have a plain number without the $ and % symbols. I've tried the whitespace analyzer and the simple analyzer but they don't consider numbers. Is there anyway to make the StandardAnalyzer not delete the $ and % in my indexed documents?

My current indexwriter code looks like this:

```
private IndexWriter createWriter() throws IOException {
    FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR));
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
    return writer;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - as far as indexing or searching is concerned, why do you need those special characters in your index? I guess, your search will work perfectly OK without those symbols.

Also, IMHO, if those are numeric values, you shouldn't be using `String` or `Text` 
field types and probably, that is why you need those symbols at first place. If you are trying to build something for numeric data, you should try using fields `LongPoint` , `DoublePoint` etc .

Having said that, what you are asking is achievable with SOLR but not with plain lucene ( as far as I know ) unless you are willing to write your own analyzer.

Basically, SOLR lets you do configuration for your ananlyzers - [Using StandardTokenizerFactory with currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877567/using-standardtokenizerfactory-with-currency)  - that you wouldn't be able to do by directly using - `StandardAnalyzer` or `SimpleAnalyzer` because they do what they do - that can't be customized.

You can use builder of `org.apache.lucene.analysis.custom.CustomAnalyzer` [CustomAnalyzer Javadoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/custom/CustomAnalyzer.html) to build your custom analyzer. An analyzer basically consists of a tokenizer and multiple filters.

I am not aware of any but you can start by browsing dependency -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to see if there is any analyzer or tokenizer for your need.

But again, I feel that you wouldn't need those symbols in your index - that can be achieved by doing some pre & post processing for indexing and searching.

[How to index words with special character in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303014/how-to-index-words-with-special-character-in-solr)

Comment: you're able to build your own CustomAnalyzer with lucene as well. It's not really hard to achieve with the CustomAnalyzer.Builder:

[CustomAnalyzer Javadoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/custom/CustomAnalyzer.html)

Comment: Included your link in answer.